# AWS API Gateway Model : Invalid model schema specified

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am getting error while creating Model in aws api gateway, Json is in correct format and still it says validation error. Please anyone? where I went wrong?

Error message "Invalid model specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid model schema specified]"

Json Schema i am trying to use is:

```
{
   "action":"createOrUpdate",
   "Content-Type":"application/json",
   "accept":"application/json",
   "input":[
      {
         "utm_CustomObj":"19UYA31581L000000",
         "leadId":"1071319"
      }
   ]
}
```

[Error screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYNaf.png)

Comment: The text you have here does not match what is the screenshot...

Comment: Also, it looks like you are providing an example JSON object, not a schema.

Comment: @Bob-kinney: I corrected error message, what I got is same as screen shot. 

Should I be defining rules for my JSON object here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't seem to be actually defining a schema for your data. Please refer to [the API gateway documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/models-mappings.html) for some examples of defining a model with JSON schema.

Answer (score 3):

It probably should follow Open API json format, like Api Gateway "Error" model.

Error model

```
{
   "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
   "title":"Error Schema",
   "type":"object",
   "properties":{
      "message":{
         "type":"string"
      }
   }
}
```

Find out more at: [Swagger Docs](https://swagger.io/specification/)

Answer (score -2):

Apache Velocity Template Language is the language of the model.   If you are creating a model this is the language you are using,  not JSON .